# A better MySql console for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, command-line, mysql

Actually, I am only looking for a single feature:

I would like to emulate the Bash shell's `Ctrl-r` in a MySql console.

That is to say, I type the first few characters of a previously issued command and `Ctrl-r` allows me to step back through all commands which began thus.

Any other bells & whistles are, of course, welcome.

Six years later, I realize that auto-complete on keywords and the scheme (database, table & column names) would be highly desirable.

Comment: From the specifications given, may I point out that the `mysql` command-line client does exactly that? :)

Comment: Mine doesn't - not on Windows. I use the standard MySql install and while I can go backward through the command history using up arrow, I cannot search for commands beginning with a given text.  Or, **can** I? How?

Comment: Oh, Windows... Sorry, no idea (the only windows I have are for light and fresh air). I was assuming Bash → Linux... Well, my fault. You wrote "for Windows" and had the tag there. But now, it could still have been working on Windows as well – you didn't state having tried the CLI :)

Comment: NVm, it was a good comment for a Saturday evening ;-) That's the frustration. Window has special terminal for MySql, but it is **extremely** basic :-(

Comment: Seems to be the opposite combination to Oracle's `sqlplus` – which has all those features in the Windows version, but lacks them on *nix (not even basic readline support there). OK, I must pass here – but hopefully someone else knows about something. Good luck!